# How to use Get to parse multiple JSON files?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having some trouble parsing more than one JSON file at a time.

Basically, I have a web form with checkboxes that control which polygons to draw on a Google Map.

Depending what the user selects, that determines which JSON files (and geo coordinates) to get and parse. The script below works except for the last step - it always only returns the very last JSON file regardless how many are selected.

This is my first post to *Stackoverflow* and I'm new to JS, so any suggestions or different ways to approach this problem would be appreciated!

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { //parse json file
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
              var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
              console.log(myArr);
         }
    }

function goCheck() { 
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var checkboxCount = 0;
var selections = [];
var urlArray = [];

for (var i=0, length = input.length; i<length; i++) { 
     if (input[i].checked === true) {
     j = input[i].value;
     selections.push(j); // store values for checkbox selections in array
     checkboxCount++; // keep track how many were checked

     var url = "https://mywebsite.ca/" + j + ".txt";
     urlArray.push(url); // store urls in array
   }
}

console.log(checkboxCount); // number of boxes checked
console.log(selections); // array with the selection values
console.log(urlArray); // an array with the json urls

// 2nd Loop  - iterate over URL array and call function to get json object

for (var i=0, length = urlArray.length; i<length; i++) {

      console.log(urlArray[i]);// check that loop is working
      xmlhttp.open("GET", urlArray[i], true);
      xmlhttp.send();  

}}
```

Comment: Ok, I think I have it working... I updated the scripts with lfac's and jball's changes and then changed `xmlhttp.open("GET", urlArray[i], true);` to `xmlhttp.open("GET", urlArray[i], false);` - that seemed to do it. I'll need to test some more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reassigning what `xmlhttp` is doing each time. Create a new var each time and assign the state change handler to it and it should work. E.g.

```
for (var i=0, length = urlArray.length; i<length; i++) {    
      console.log(urlArray[i]);// check that loop is working
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { //parse json file
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            console.log(myArr);
         }
      }; 
      xmlhttp.open("GET", urlArray[i], true);
      xmlhttp.send();  

}}
```

When you recall `open` on the same `XMLHttpRequest` you are abandoning the last request, but if you create a new one each time, they will each handle their own requests.

Aside, if you have control over the server side, a server method that takes in an array of files to get and returns a json array in a single AJAX call seems like the way to go long term.

Comment: Ok, I gave that a try but I must be missing something. It's still only returning the last request in the loop - so it;s still abandoning the previous requests. I got the same results from Lfac's suggestions above too. Good idea about the server side method!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a new XMLHttpRequest for each file. Replace your last loop with:

```js
var xmlhttp;

for (var i=0, length = urlArray.length; i<length; i++) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { //parse json file
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
              var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
              console.log(myArr);
         }
    }

    console.log(urlArray[i]);// check that loop is working
    xmlhttp.open("GET", urlArray[i], true);
    xmlhttp.send();  
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm still finding that the initial http request is getting replaced or overridden by the next request in the loop.  Not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: So the loop is working and retrieving all the JSON files and data. The problem seems to be when trying to **parse** the responses - it only performs it on the last xmlhttp request.